# Populating SQL Table values based a condition and a date range

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a SQL table with 4 columns: 'date', 'machine', 'failure' and 'warning'.

The date column has sequential dates (day by day), but repeats the same dates for different machines. The failure column is 0s and 1s.

The warning column is currently blank. I want to populate the warning column values with '1' for the machine in question on every date for 30 days before a failure (i.e. when a '1' appears in the failure column).

How can I write a query for this? Is it necessary to create another table?

Here's what I've tried:

```
UPDATE mytable (warning)
SET warning = 1
WHERE (Failure = 1) AND (date BETWEEN (date - 30) AND date)
```

But this does not work since it excludes the fields that do not have a failure, but are still within 30 days of a failure.

I've also tried isolating the machine and dates in question:

```
SELECT date, machine
FROM mytable
WHERE (Failure = 1)
```

But I'm not sure how to reconcile this subset with populating the fields in the full table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm looking for a generic SQL approach because this is actually for Apache Spark SQL.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name - it's for use in Apache spark SQL

Comment: I think is better if you provide some sample data and desire output.

Comment: `(date BETWEEN (date - 30) AND date)` is always true.  BTW: `date` is a bad name for a column.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method for doing this using an `exists` clause to set `warning`:

```
update sqltable t
    set warning = 1
    where exists (select 1
                  from sqltable t2
                  where t2.machine = t.machine and
                        t2.failure = 1 and
                        t2.date between (t1.date - 30) AND t1.date)
                 );
```

This is standard SQL, but I'm not 100% sure it will work on Apache Spark SQL.

Comment: This looks like what I'm after - will give it a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I really dont understand when you update but you need `UPDATE` not `INSERT`

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET warning = 0
```

THEN

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET warning = 1
WHERE (Failure = 1) AND (date BETWEEN (date - 30) AND date)
```